# ¿Como puedo lograr que css grid con imagenes sea responsive?

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

Mi contenedor no se ajusta al tamaño de la pantalla, como puedo hacer para que si lo haga?
Mi codigo:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}



h4{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.contenedor{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,200px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3,auto);
    max-width: 800px;
    gap: 0;
    margin: auto;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.item1{
    grid-column: 1/3;
    grid-row: 1/3;
}

.item2{
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/3;
}

.item3{
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 3/3;
}

.item4{
    grid-column: 3/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}

.item5{
    grid-column: 4/4;
    grid-row: 1/2;
}

.item6{
    grid-column: 3/5;
    grid-row: 2/4;
}


/* Estilos en todos los componentes */

*{
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h4>Peliculas en cartelera</h4>
<hr>

<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="item1"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item2"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item3"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>  
  <div class="item4"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item5"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="item6"><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w400/ww7eC3BqSbFsyE5H5qMde8WkxJ2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Mi resultado final:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner alguna captura del resultado final?

Comment: Hola! , te recomiendo para el manejo de grids que puedas utilizar frameworks como Bootstrap que te van a permitir manejar de una manera super fácil los tamaños de pantallas, te dejo el enlace de manejo de grids https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Ahí puse una captura @hawks

Comment: Gracias @JavierAmaya, pero quiero intentar hacerlo con css grid

Comment: tendras que usar media queries para adaptar tu diseño.

Comment: @hawks No hay manera de que se achique el contenedor junto con las imagenes?

Comment: puedes intentar implementar tu diseño con la unidad fraccional de tamaño `fr`. https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/

Comment: Ya lo pude solucionar con esto: grid-template-columns: repeat(auto,200px); gracias!!